# Django/MongoDB tutorials for beginner

Tags: django, mongodb

I'm a beginner and don't have any prior experience with web application development. So far, I only did some CLI programming. Could anyone suggest me how to start working with Django and MongoDB?

Comment: [Mongo db](http://www.mongodb.org/#) has an online shell for beginners. You should give it a try.

Comment: Google search? http://django-mongodb.org/

Comment: For MongoDB you can refer : https://www.tutorialkart.com/mongodb/mongodb-tutorial/

Answer (score 5):

There is a free education courses for MongoDB, one being [developer-foccussed](https://education.10gen.com/courses/10gen/M101/2012_Fall/about) and the other more [administration-focussed](https://education.10gen.com/courses/10gen/M102/2012_Fall/about). There is still time to sign up afaik so I'd recommend having a look at the developer course (it's taught by Dwight Merriman, the 10gen CEO).

MongoDB tutorials can be found [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/).

There's a short doc on using [MongoEngine with Django](http://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/django.html). The MongoEngine maintainer wrote a tutorial [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-a-tumblelog-application-with-django-mongodb-engine/) on writing an app with MongoEngine and Django.

Answer (score 3):

When you want to learn web application development, you should first learn how to create static HTML pages with a text editor, so you get a feeling for how the WWW actually works.

When you have a solid understanding of HTML and CSS, you can start with dynamic website generation using Django.

Using a database like MongoDB is an entirely different beast you should tackle after you've learned how to generate websites server-sided.